# Proving the subset property of the Outer Lebesgue Measure

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Here's what I'm proving now;

Let $A \subseteq B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $\lambda(A) \leq \lambda(B)$, where $\lambda$ refers to the Outer Lebesgue Measure.

---

Proof Attempt:

Suppose that $\lambda(A) > \lambda(B)$. By definition, there has to exist a set of open intervals $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ such that:

$$\lambda(A) > \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |I_j| \geq \lambda(B)$$

and $B \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} I_j$. Otherwise, $\lambda(B)$ cannot be the infimum of the set:

$$\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |I_k|: B \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k \land I_k \text{is an open interval} \right\}$$

which is not possible. But since $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ covers $B$, it also covers $A$ and so, by definition, we have:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |I_j| \geq \lambda(A) > \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |I_j| \geq \lambda(B)$$

which is impossible. Hence, $\lambda(A) \leq \lambda(B)$. $\Box$

Does the above proof work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Relax, it works fine.

Comment: Oh damn, thank you very much